# Помогите запустить проект на vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Глупая просьба, но я туплю)
Не могу запустить проект, вроде бы все делаю по иструкции, но не выходит

Подключаю базу firebase, но выдает следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же нужно продублировать раздел

Ссылка на проект: https://github.com/vladilenm/vue-practice-youtube

Comment: Вам всё написали же, установите зависимости проекта командой `npm i`

Comment: Читал, устанавливал, но все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: Какую на этот раз?

Comment: npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/firebase/app.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

Comment: Попробуйте так: npm i firebase

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы успешно запустить Ваш проект, Вам нужно иметь менеджер версий Node и последовать следующим шагам инструкции.

- `sudo npm i -g n` для установки менеджера версий Node
- `sudo n 8.17.0` для установки Node 8.17.0
- `sudo n` для отображения списка доступных версий, которые были ранее скачаны с помощью `n`

Появится список и выберите версию, которая указана на скриншоте ниже:

[image: Список доступных версий]

После, запустите следующий ряд комманд:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:vladilenm/vue-practice-youtube.git
cd vue-practice-youtube
npm i
npm run serve
```

Из-за того, что Firebase был написан без поддержки Node 9+, поэтому `build` и не происходит.
У меня всё заработало, как можете видеть со скриншота ниже.

[image: Vue CRM Practice]

**UPD.1** : Для Windows используйте PowerShell из-под администратора и без ключевого слова `sudo`. `sudo` используеться в Unix системах.
Также, для того, чтобы проще было устанавливать пакеты и прочие приложения используйте [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)